# Aggregate by string column name in R

Tags: r

I would like to group data in a data.frame by two columns and then sum a specific third column.  For example:

```
> aggregate(mpg~gear+cyl, data=mtcars, FUN=sum)
  gear cyl   mpg
1    3   4  21.5
2    4   4 215.4
3    5   4  56.4
4    3   6  39.5
5    4   6  79.0
6    5   6  19.7
7    3   8 180.6
8    5   8  30.8
```

Now, I need to do this several times for different columns.  So I would like to write a function which generalizes this.  It take the data.frame and one of the columns (to keep things simple) and does the same thing.

```
agg.data <- function(df, colname) {
  aggregate(mpg~gear+colname, data=df, FUN=sum) 
}
```

Running this will produce:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'colname' not found
```

How can I pass in the value of colname to aggregate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Paste together a string representation of your formula, and give that string as an argument to formula()...

```
agg.data <- function(df, colname) {
  aggregate(formula(paste0("mpg~gear+", colname)), data=df, FUN=sum) 
}

> agg.data(mtcars, "cyl")
  gear cyl   mpg
1    3   4  21.5
2    4   4 215.4
3    5   4  56.4
4    3   6  39.5
5    4   6  79.0
6    5   6  19.7
7    3   8 180.6
8    5   8  30.8
```

Comment: You''ll probably want to change to `data=df` within the function and then to `agg.data(mtcars, "cyl")`, because `cars` is entirely different data set.

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`:

```
fun.dt <- function(dt, col) {
    dt[, .(mpg=sum(mpg)), by=c("gear", col)]
}

require(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(mtcars)
fun.dt(dt, "cyl")
#    gear cyl   mpg
# 1:    4   6  79.0
# 2:    4   4 215.4
# 3:    3   6  39.5
# 4:    3   8 180.6
# 5:    3   4  21.5
# 6:    5   4  56.4
# 7:    5   8  30.8
# 8:    5   6  19.7
```

The `by` expression in *data.tables* can also take a character vector of column names in addition to lists of columns/expressions. We can simply provide a character vector to the `by` argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use the "normal" `aggregate` interface (i.e. not the formula interface) to supply column names in variables. The syntax is slightly different but still easy enough and doesn't require pasting:

```
agg.data2 <- function(df, colname) {
  aggregate(df[["mpg"]], list(df[["gear"]], df[[colname]]), FUN=sum) 
}
agg.data2(mtcars, "cyl")
#  Group.1 Group.2     x
#1       3       4  21.5
#2       4       4 215.4
#3       5       4  56.4
#4       3       6  39.5
#5       4       6  79.0
#6       5       6  19.7
#7       3       8 180.6
#8       5       8  30.8
```

---

Here's the dplyr equivalent:

```
library(dplyr)
agg.data.dplyr <- function(df, colname) {
  df %>%
    group_by_(.dots = c("gear", colname)) %>%
    summarise(sum = sum(mpg)) %>%
    ungroup()
}
agg.data.dplyr(mtcars, "cyl")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass an unquoted column name using `deparse` and `substitute`

```
agg.data <- function(df, colname) {
  aggregate(df$mpg, list(df$gear, df[, deparse(substitute(colname))]), FUN=sum) 
}

agg.data(mtcars, cyl)
#   Group.1 Group.2     x
# 1       3       4  21.5
# 2       4       4 215.4
# 3       5       4  56.4
# 4       3       6  39.5
# 5       4       6  79.0
# 6       5       6  19.7
# 7       3       8 180.6
# 8       5       8  30.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in the style of `ggplot` or `with` that allows you to just write the colnames as they are without passing a string by using `substitute`.

```
agg.data3 = function (df, colname){
    colname = substitute(colname)
    colname = as.character(colname)
    aggregate(formula(paste0("mpg~gear+", colname)), data=mtcars, FUN=sum)
}
```

usage

```
agg.data3(cars, cyl)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably find a function for that on tidyverse, however, there goes a function I often use for summary aggregation. It embbeds much of what was discussed above with `formula()` but in a more general form:

```
get.stat = function(df,var.nm,agg.id){

  #--- df       data.frame for aggregation
  #--- var.nm   target variable to be aggregated
  #--- agg.id   index name for aggretation (single value or vector)

  #--- generate aggregation formula
  agg.formula = paste(agg.id, collapse = "+")

  #--- df with summary results
  df.res = data.frame(mean    = aggregate(formula(paste0(var.nm,"~",agg.formula)), df, mean  )[,length(agg.id)+1],
                      median  = aggregate(formula(paste0(var.nm,"~",agg.formula)), df, median)[,length(agg.id)+1],
                      sd      = aggregate(formula(paste0(var.nm,"~",agg.formula)), df, sd    )[,length(agg.id)+1],
                      min     = aggregate(formula(paste0(var.nm,"~",agg.formula)), df, min   )[,length(agg.id)+1],
                      max     = aggregate(formula(paste0(var.nm,"~",agg.formula)), df, max   )[,length(agg.id)+1],
                      sum     = aggregate(formula(paste0(var.nm,"~",agg.formula)), df, sum   )[,length(agg.id)+1],
                      count   = aggregate(formula(paste0(var.nm,"~",agg.formula)), df, length)[,length(agg.id)+1])

  #--- bind indexers
  for(c in 1:length(agg.id)){
    df.res = cbind(df.res, aggregate(formula(paste0(var.nm,"~",agg.formula)), df, mean)[,c])
    colnames(df.res)[length(colnames(df.res))] = agg.id[c]
  }

  #--- re-order col
  df.res = df.res[,c(agg.id,colnames(df.res)[1:(length(colnames(df.res)) - c)])]

  return(df.res)
}
```

With that function loaded, you can simply:

`get.stat(df, "mpg",c("gear","cyl"))`