# R trying to do a for loop, error

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to do a for loop like this:

```
 for (n in 1:200)
  {
pre[n] <- aggregate(S[n]~Secs[n], data = dataframe, FUN = sum)   
freqsdf[n] <- data.frame(table(SecsOnly2$Secs[n])) 
AVAL[n] <- pre[n]$S[n]/freqsdf[n]$Freq
AVAL[n] <- data.frame(AVAL[n])
hist(dataframe$Secs[n], xlab = "", ylab = "", ylim = c(0, 16000), axes = FALSE, col = "grey")
axis(4, ylim = c(0, 16000), col = "black", col.axis = "black", las = 2, cex.axis = .5)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(pre[n]$Secs[n], AVAL[n], col = "red" , type = "l")
abline(h = 0.25) }
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'S' not found
```

My dataset that has the "S" variable has a bunch of variables including "S1" through "S200." I want R to go through all this code for all the "S" variables, the "Secs" variables, etc... This code worked fine for just S1, when I wrote it just for S1, Secs1, etc...(not in a loop). But I want R to go through the same code for all my columns. I'm not sure why "S" is not being found. I thought by going from n = 1 to n = 200, R automatically looks for "S1", "Secs1," etc... the first time the loop runs, and then "S2", "Secs2," etc... the second time it runs, and so on.

Comment: I don't know about fixing the formula inside the aggregate call, but the other places where you use `x$S[n]`, you should be using something like `x[[paste0("S",n)]]`. The two problems are: `S[n]` does not get parsed the way you imagine; and `$` only plays nice with plain strings to its right (but `[[]]` is an alternative with similar functionality).

Comment: Thanks Frank. So I'm supposed to use this kind of format x[[paste0("S",n)]] for all the places where I need the loop to happen?

Comment: Yeah, that should work in most places. I think it will not work for the first argument of `aggregate`, however. Probably someone else knows a fix there. Also, many of the objects you are assigning to should probably be `list`s, initialized to, e.g., `pre <- list()` outside of the loop and assigned to like `pre[[n]] <- value` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks again Frank. I'll try out all these suggestions. Hopefully it'll work now.

Comment: You were right, Frank. i am getting this error now:Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Comment: I don't really use `aggregate`, but this Q&A might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28863133/1191259 Looks like more use of `paste` could do the trick.

Comment: Nothing is working for me... The aggregate's fun = sum has to be altered somehow, I think, but I don't know how. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81331/discussion-between-frank-and-user2714330).

Answer (score 0):

In this line (and several other places):

```
pre[n]$S[n]/freqsdf[n]$Freq
```

You are trying to paste together `S` or `Secs` and the `[n]` you are using to subset the S01 columns, but R is interpreting it as you trying to take the nth item from `S` which does not exist. It's hard to fix without seeing your data, but you could try replacing every place you try and do this trick with something like:

```
pre[n][[paste("S", n, sep="")]]
```

Comment: jeremycg, do you know what I should do given my error:Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument